# Importing an external js file into another external js file

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core-mvc

In my ASP.Net Core MVC Application I have separate .js files for few pages, They contain normal validation and client side logic.

I have to put few method in a common util.js file and this file methods will be shared among another js files.

but I am not able to add the reference of this util.js into other external js files.

I have tried few approaches as

For example  My util.js

```
export function ShowAlert(val) {
alert(val);
}
```

And than in another js file (MyApp.js) with import statement

```
import { ShowAlert } from './util'

function Info() {
    var F = document.getElementsByName('txtFName')[0].value
    var L = document.getElementsByName('txtLName')[0].value
    if (F.length > 0 && L.length > 0)
        ShowAlert(F + ' ' + L)
    else
        ShowAlert('Fields Required');
}
```

But it give error in import statement line

> Unexpected token {

Than I tried babel tool to get browser compatible js, which is

```
//import { ShowAlert } from './util'
var _util = require('./util');

function Info() {
    var F = document.getElementsByName('txtFName')[0].value
    var L = document.getElementsByName('txtLName')[0].value
    if (F.length > 0 && L.length > 0)
        _util.ShowAlert(F + ' ' + L)
    else
        _util.ShowAlert('Fields Required');
}
```

Now it says require is not defined , so after searching few post on internet I found a solution and included require.js before MyApp.js

```
<script src="./require.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="./MyApp.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

But still the error is

> Module name "util" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])

How can I have reference of one js file into another and why import is giving error here?

**Update 1**

Util.js

```
export default function ShowAlert(val) {
alert(val);}
```

MyApp.js

```
import { ShowAlert } from './util';
//var _util = require('./util');
function Info() {
    var F = document.getElementsByName('txtFName')[0].value
    var L = document.getElementsByName('txtLName')[0].value
    if (F.length > 0 && L.length > 0)
        ShowAlert(F + ' ' + L)
    else
        ShowAlert('Fields Required');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. add type="module" to your app.ja ( main script)

> `<script src="MyApp.js" type="module"></script>`

2. seperate function and export do it like that (more readable):

`function ShowAlert(val) { alert(val); } export { ShowAlert }`

If you would lieke to export more functions do it liek that:

```
 export { ShowAlert ,  ShowAlert1 , ShowAlert2 , ShowAlert2}
```

3. Run your script on HTTP serwer

Comment: if you need to do it in 1 line add default just after export but you will have to change import state also. if you will separate export file, import wont change and it should work if not. let me know

Comment: ouch... your js files are in 1 folder?

Comment: yes , they are in same folder and check update 1 , but still it give error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187548/discussion-between-saurabh-and-piotr-mirosz).

Answer (score 1):

To use JavaScript modules on the client-side you need:

- A [browser which supports them](https://caniuse.com/#feat=es6-module)
- To declare that you are using them with `type="module"`

For example:

*index.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Test</title>
<h1>Test</h1>
<script type="module" src="main.js"></script>
```

*main.js*

```
import {sum} from './module.js';

const value = sum(1,2);
const node = document.createTextNode(value);
document.body.appendChild(node);
```

*module.js*

```
function sum(a,b) {
    return a + b;
}

export { sum }
```